# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED - frequent error message

Tags: windows

I use a broadband, and i get these error frequently and intermittently while trying to open any websites.

1. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
2. DNS_PROBE_STARTED
3. DNS Probe finished
4. If i restart the router the error goes away for a while but they come back,

This is not specific to one laptop, but happens to all devices in my home.

any idea what can be causing this ?

Regards,
R

Comment: If the router belongs to the ISP, call their Support. Otherwise, try to find a firmware update from its manufacturer, or try another router.

Comment: You could also try another DNS provider instead of using the default ISP's, such as [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/)'s `1.1.1.1`